# Flexslider - thubmnail slider stops slide show on click carousal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexslider

I want to implement Flexslider, so I used "Slider w/thumbnail slider" from their home page. Everything fine and working, but I noticed one thing. If I click on any carousel element, it stops the Slideshow. After I need to click on each carousel item to see the slides.

So Is there any option to stop this behavior? I have just made a Fiddle with basic configs to show this.

[here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/salih/b2ud3jL3/)

code:

```
$('#carousel').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    controlNav: false,
    animationLoop: false,
    slideshow: false,
    itemWidth: 210,
    itemMargin: 5,
    asNavFor: '#slider'
});

$('#slider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    controlNav: false,
    animationLoop: false,
    slideshow: true,
    sync: "#carousel"
});
```

Comment: I didn't catch the behavior on Google Chrome v45. Is there any specific detail you can give?

Comment: `pauseOnAction: false` you can try this option for `flexSlider` as by default it is set to `true`.

Comment: I didn't catch such behavior in Chrome V45 and Firefox V41. Can you provide more details?

Comment: @ebilgin please check the fiddle, in any browser. just let it play the slide show, the click any of the carousal item below. the main slideshow will be stopped

Comment: @AjayKulkarni please check the fiddle, in any browser. just let it play the slide show, the click any of the carousal item below. the main slideshow will be stopped

Comment: @SalihK Sorry, still same such behavior, I couldn't catch.

Comment: @ebilgin - If you are using this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/salih/b2ud3jL3/, may be I didnt explain well about the issue, see the slideshow, carousal works as as a manual control right, and Slideshow(#slider) is set to slideshow=true, and if you click on carousal(#carousal) item Slideshow(#slider) stops its auto play, ie, it turns some thing like this slideshow=false

Comment: @vivekkupadhyay pauseOnAction: false works on #slider, but if i click on carousal (#carousal) item #slider pauses

Comment: @vivekkupadhyay agreed your first comment! See my answer and thank you for solving!

Answer (score 0):

After seven years this was asked, I can confirm what vivekkupadhyay wrote in his first comment: it is enough to set `pauseOnAction: false,` instead of `pauseOnAction: true,` inside

```
$.flexslider.defaults = {

};
```

at the bottom of the js file.